# Wrong _id field using mongodb-memory-server and jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jestjs

I have an express controller that creates a new Post document like this

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.uid });
        if (!user) throw new ServerError(
            "user with provided authorid doesn't exist",
            400
        );

        const newPost = new Post({
            author: req.uid,
            title: req.body.title,
            caption: req.body.caption,
            media: req.body.media,
            location: req.body.location
        });

        const createdPost = await newPost.save();

        res.status(201).send(createdPost);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};
```

When tested with postman it works as intended and the _id field shows no problems

```
{
    author: "LJFlAgRjqXQ1K7HUSyj12EmxxXD2",
    title: "title",
    caption: "caption",
    comments: [],
    media: [],
    likes: [],
    location: { coordinates: [] },
    _id: "61af0c16423073390394717d", // _id as expected
    date: "2021-12-07T07:24:06.809Z",
    __v: 0
}
```

But when testing the same controller with Jest and mongodb-memory-server, the _id field turns to be a call to the ObjectId construtor instead of being a new id

```
{
    author: "61af0c43870651bbd1a7a81d",
    title: "title",
    caption: "caption",
    comments: [],
    media: [],
    likes: [],
    location: { coordinates: [] },
    _id: new ObjectId("61af0c43870651bbd1a7a820"), // _id is a constructor call
    date: "2021-12-07T07:24:51.653Z",
    __v: 0
}
```

is this an issue with mongodb-memory-server? how would I get the correct id of the post to use it in a test?

Comment: Why do you think there's an issue? The difference you're seeing is just in the way that the ObjectId instance, which lower-level tests see, is _serialised_ to JSON, which the API exposes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So that's how it's supposed to look like in tests? If I have another controller called getPostById which takes an id in the request, how would I use the id of the new created post in the test? If I pass it the way it currently is, getPostById would get `new ObjectId("61af0c43870651bbd1a7a820")` instead of an actual id

Comment: I see now, I can just use JSON.stringify() to serialize the object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note you shouldn't really be unit testing controllers, as you don't own their API (Express's request and response objects and the next function). Extract the actual domain logic to a service, and unit test _that_.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make use of `_id.toString()` as described in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)

Or an alternative could be make use of `valueOf()` e.g `expect(post._id.valueOf()).toBe("61af0c43870651bbd1a7a820")`